# How to automatically enable an outlook rule after it fails?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, mail-rule

I have many rules enabled in my Outlook 2007, many rules fail and get disabled this creates a mess in my inbox. Is it possible for me automatically enable rule after it fails due to an offending email ?

Comment: Have you thought about looking at the rule to see why it fails and see if you can work around it? :/

Comment: Sometimes it fails as the message has attachment. Most of the time I am clueless why the rules fail

Comment: it also fails if you have too many rules how many rules have you setup?

Comment: I have 64 rules set up in my outlook 2007

Answer (score 1):

Have you upgraded to Outlook 2007 from a previous version ?
If so, you might need to recreate the rules that fail.

The following Microsoft article states that there is a limit on the total textual length of
the rules, which might be as low as 32 KB. If you have many long rules, you could be hitting this limit :
[Some rules are disabled, and you receive an error message when you try to enable them after you upgrade to Outlook 2010, to Outlook 2007, or to Outlook 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/886616)

The article [Troubleshoot rules](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/troubleshoot-rules-HP005242904.aspx) also says :

> If you see the word "failed" in the name of your rule, it means that
>   Outlook was unable to successfully import your entire rule. The most
>   common cause of import failure is that the rule is too complex; for
>   example, it has too many conditions. You should examine and manually
>   modify these rules.

Another [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195559) explains why a rule that forwards mail to the Internet may fail if you are connecting to an Exchange server.